# catch nested_attributes on create to stop duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

Using Rails, I have the following form...

**Events#New - Form Partial**

```
<%= simple_form_for @event, multipart: true do |f| %>

  ...

  <% unless signed_in? %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :user do |u| %>
      <%= u.input :name %>
      <%= u.input :email %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  ...

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Once that form is submitted it will create the form and the nested_attribute. Which an Event belongs to one user.

**Event Model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

However my issue is, these fields are required and you don't need to be logged in to submit this form.

What I want is when you fill out the form and the user email exists it should just add the event to that user, otherwise it should create a new User record. *Right now all it does is add additional user records.*

I managed to get something working in the way of not using nested_attributes and just accepting the `params[:name]` and `params[:email]` then did a check, if it exists added it as a `User.find_by(email: params[:email]).builds.events(event_params)` but I wanted to directly modify the way the model handles the data as I feel the controller isn't the right place for this logic.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use nested attributes, go for a form class approach, see section *"3. Extract Form Objects"* on http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ for one way how to do it,

nested attributes have a way of biting you over and over again and you just found one of them

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I imagine the form view would have to change simple_fields_for and just have plain text_field_tags?

Comment: Yes, just plain old tags like you would with a "normal crud" on a model and validators and persistence would be handled by the form class. I built a very nice form class gem that delegates model validators to the form and all sorts of nice gimmicks but I'm a bad person and haven't written any docs yet https://github.com/bbozo/simple_form_class. If you're interested I'll make an effort and put out some examples

Comment: `User.find_or_create_by(email: event_params([:user_attributes][:email])` returns `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

Comment: We're kinda chatting this up and we shouldn't so I'll remove this comment later. Use http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails to make heads and tails whats going on in that controller and things will get clear, ask another question on SO if you get stuck